# $C(K)^{*}$ in the weak*-topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

It is clear that for a compact Hausdorff space $K$ the space of continuous complex (or real) functions $C(K)$ is a Banach space with the "sup" norm. What's not clear to me is whether there exists a homeomorphism between $K$ and the dual space $C(K)^{*}$ equipped with the weak*-topology. My guess is it would have to be linear and well defined in some special way.

Rudin's $\textit{Functional Analysis}$ suggests choosing a point $p \in K$ and defining $\Lambda_{p} \in C(K)^{*}$ by $\Lambda_{p}(f)= f(p)$ (I think this justifies the existence of a weak*-topology on $C(K)^{*}$). Then the claim is that $p \mapsto \Lambda_{p}$ is the homeomorphism we want. Then again, this map is not onto, so calling it a homeomorphism doesn't seem to make sense at this point.

Comment: I don't quite get what you are asking?

Comment: The map suggested by Rudin is not onto. It gives a homeomorphism between $K$ and the set of nontrivial complex homomorphisms of $C(K)$, which is a subset of $C(K)^*$.

Comment: My question is that I want to know how to show that $p \mapsto \Lambda_{p}$ is a homeomorphism between $K$ and $C(K)^{*}$ equipped with the weak*-topology. What I stated in my second to last sentence was what I could conclude from showing the homeomorphism.

Comment: @AGM: Then is the map an embedding?

Comment: My point is that it cannot be a homeomorphism since it is not onto. Perhaps what you want to show is that $K$ is homeomorphic to a particular subset of $C(K)^*$ in the weak$^*$-topology? Edit: yes, it should be an embedding.

Comment: @AGM: Yes, I think that is what I want.

Comment: If you're familiar with $C^*$-algebras, the following page may also be helpful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfand_representation

Comment: @AGM: In my course in functional analysis, we haven't even gotten to that point in discussing $C^{*}$-algebras and how they relate to this particular issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most natural map from a compact (nice, topological) space $K$ to $C^o(K)$ is $x\to \delta_x$, meaning $x\to (f \to f(x))$. This is a continuous linear functional when $C^o(K)$ is given the sup-norm topology (and convenient that $K$ is compact, so there's no issue of uniform-ness...).

But there are many other continuous linear functionals, unless $K$ is discrete, hence finite (or weird...)

EDIT: and/but re-reading the question, I don't understand the goal of the questioner. That is, I have the suspicion that the literal question is not the underlying question... ?

EDIT-EDIT: after clarification: to show that this map is a homeomorphism _to_its_image_, first, given continuous $f$ and $\epsilon>0$ and $x\in K$, there is a neighborhood $N$ of $x$ such that for $y\in N$ $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$, which is the continuity of $x\to \delta_x$. The map is injective because $K$ is presumably Hausdorff, so Urysohn's lemma gives functions separating points. To prove the map is open-to-its-image is to show that $\delta_x$ close to $\delta_y$ implies $x$ is close to $y$ in $K$. The contrapositive is that $x$ far from $y$ in $K$ implies $\delta_x$ is far from $\delta_y$. Again use Urysohn's lemma...

Comment: My intended goal is to show that Rudin's map is an embedding.

Answer (score 1):

$K$ is certainly not homeomorphic to the dual space $C(K)^*$ because the latter is never compact. $K$ is homeomorphic to the unit ball of $C(K)^*$ endowed with the weak* topology.

Comment: Actually, $K$ is homeomorphic only to a subset of the unit ball of $C(K)^\ast$.  For example, if $K$ is infinite and coutable, then that ball is uncountable...